# Levenshtein algorithm in Java

Tags: java, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to implement Levenshtein's algorithm in Java, inspired from this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Iterative_with_two_matrix_rows)

```
public static int indicator(char a, char b) {
    return (a == b) ? 0 : 1;
}

public static int levenshtein(String token1, String token2) {
    int[] levi = new int[token2.length() + 1];
    int[] levi_1 = new int[token2.length() + 1];

    // initialize column i=0
    for (int j = 0; j <= token2.length(); j++)
        levi_1[j] = j;

    // columns i=1 -> i=len(token1)
    for (int i = 1; i <= token1.length(); i++) {
        // lev_a,b(i,0) = i
        levi[0] = i;
        // update rest of column i
        for (int j = 1; j <= token2.length(); j++) {
            levi[j] = Math.min(Math.min(levi_1[j] + 1, levi[j - 1] + 1),
                               levi_1[j - 1] + indicator(token1.charAt(i - 1), token2.charAt(j - 1)));
        }

        // save column i to update column i+1
        levi_1 = levi;
    }

    return levi[token2.length()];
}
```

But testing this on string "Maus" and "Haus" gives me an incorrect answer of 4. Can you help me with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `indicator` method?

Comment: added it to the code.

Comment: What does your method return? I see that it should output an integer, is it `levi[levi.length - 1]`?

Comment: fixed it. yeah it returns that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from this line:

```
levi_1 = levi;
```

This line doesn't change every value from the `levi_1` array, it only changes its reference; the values are still the same when you call `levi_1[0]`, `levi_1[1]`, etc.

I would suggest you to write those lines instead:

```
for (int k = 0; k < levi.length; k++)
    levi_1[k] = levi[k];
```